# Define global function in Kotlin that I be used in html file to use as onclick callback

Tags: javascript, kotlin

I want to define a function inside Kotlin/transpiled JavaScript, that I can pass "in it's raw and global form" to some inputs inside my html.
With raw form, I mean not as [project  name].doClick().

```
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="doClick();>
```

Comment: Ah, I see. You know about fully qualified reference. Is there any reason you don't want to pass it?

Comment: @AlexeyAndreev Hmm... I don't know, what fully qualified references are :P. The only reason, I don't want to pass it with namespace prefix is for sake of look. It looks more "simple javascript" and nicer to me. HelI can't even descripe, why I want to avoid that. I guess there's no proper reason and I'm gonna just use a namespace.
EDIT: I'm not a Web developer _at all_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling with similar problem, although specifying a module was not enough in my case.
So referring to the initial question `Define global function in Kotlin` I would suggest a workaround:

```
import kotlin.browser.window

fun main() {
    window.asDynamic()["doClick"] = ::doClick
}

fun doClick() {
    println("Hello, world")
}
```

In this code a kotlin function is explicitly assigned to a variable in global scope. Now you can simply call your function using `doClick()`

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have module named `sample`, with either `plain` or `UMD` module type. It's content is following:

```
package foo

fun doClick() {
    println("Hello, world")
}
```

Then you can assign it to click handler as follows:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="sample.foo.doClick();>
```

See [documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-to-kotlin-interop.html) for details.